# How should I denote "ignore this column" of a matrix?

Tags: matrices, notation, article-writing

I have a question about notation. I have arrived at a matrix, the first two columns of which I'm labeling for future reference. I don't care about and won't be using the third column. It will be clear to the reader from the context I provide, but I'd like to know if there's a standard method of saying "ignore this column". What I'm using now is:
$$\begin{bmatrix}
| & | & |\\ 
\omega_1  & \omega_2  & \sim \\ 
| & | & | \\ 
\end{bmatrix}$$

Good enough? Just curious if there's a tried and true method in the math community.

Comment: If I understand you correctly, simply a $"*"$ as an entry is sometimes used to denote an arbitrary entry, so you can make a column of stars.

Comment: I’d just put a star in the middle of the column, people generally understand that notation

Comment: I have seen more than once the " \check" symbol $1,2, \cdots, i-1,\check{i},i+1, \cdots n$ used for that.

Comment: Why not just label it $\omega_3$, then never do anything with it?  I mean, I would feel very comfortable writing "Let $\omega_j$ be the $j$-th column of the matrix $M$" or some such, then simply never referring to the columns I don't care about.

Comment: What is the size of your matrix? What kind of coefficients do you have?

Comment: @pitariver and Nephanth thank you! that's what i was looking for.